# How do I filter JSON using jq based on if an attribute value is in an array?

Tags: json, filtering, jq

I have some JSON that I need to filter based on whether certain attribute values are present in an array.

I have something that works but if feels like a kludge. Is there a neater way of doing this?

Input

```
{"potato":4}
```

Filter

```
select(.potato as $k | ([1,2,3,4] | any(. == $k)))
```

Output

```
{
  "potato": 4
}
```

jqplay link
https://jqplay.org/s/Ts97jkk21K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this seem less of a kludge?

```
[1,2,3,4] as $acceptable
| .potato as $k
| select( any($acceptable[];  . == $k) )
```

If your jq has `IN/1`, you could skip the `$k`:

```
[1,2,3,4] as $acceptable
| select(.potato | IN($acceptable[]))
```

This style makes it easy to pass `$acceptable` in as a command-line parameter, for example.

### Temptation

It is easy to be tempted by the simplicity of a select-only solution such as:

```
[1,2,3,4] as $acceptable
| select($acceptable[] == .potato)
```

This would be fine under certain circumstances, e.g. if `$acceptable` is short and does not contain duplicates (assuming we want the semantics of `any`). But `any` and `IN` have a short-circuit semantics that may be desirable, e.g. for efficiency.

Comment: I think the middle solution seems the nicest to me, assigning .potato to a variable was the bit that felt most off to me. Thank you.